# Chrome extension rejection

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

There has been a continuous extension rejection, even with icons, screenshots, descriptions all uploaded. Anybody has encountered the same recently?

```
Item has a blank description field, or missing icons or screenshots, and appears to be suspicious.
```

The manifest is like

```
{
  "short_name": "My Tabs",
  "name": "My Tabs",
  "description": "This extension will help uses to quickly open often visited pages.",
  "icons": {
    "16": "tabs.png",
    "48": "tabs.png",
    "128": "tabs.png"
  },
...
}
```

Comment: The web store review process is known to make little sense so I'll have to make some guesses here: 1) use separate icon files and resize each one to the correct pixel dimensions, 2) elaborate in the description, currently it's vague, there's also a typo: "uses" should be "users".

Comment: I had issues with mine as well when submitting via a new Developer dashboard. You can try submitting your extension via the old one. To get there - click 'Show More' in the bottom left corner to see the popup -> then underlined `opt-out` to navigate to the old dashboard. Maybe this will help